# generate XML using XSLT the generated XML having default namespace which should generate dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I am generating XML using XSLT.The root tag of xml should have default namespace (not know prior).

I have tried `namespace::*` but it generating empty **xmlns=""** for child element

```
<xsl:element name="MG_ROOT" namespace="namespace::*">
    <xsl:element name="MG_CHILD"></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

#### output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MG_ROOT xmlns="urn:temp:xsd:1">
   <MG_CHILD xmlns=""/>
<MG_ROOT>
```

Comment: If you don't want the child element to be in no namespace, then put it the same namespace as its parent element. -- P.S. Please post a complete example, including the input - see: [mcve].

Comment: Thank you..your suggestion work for me..

Comment: @MonicaGarud, if you are no longer seeking an answer to the question, and especially if you therefore do not intend to provide the requested MCVE, then please delete the question.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, Thanks for the feedback.  As per my above comment, It is working for me as expected. Still is it needed to delete the question ?

Comment: Yes, @MonicaGarud.  This question has received a comment that helped you resolve the problem that inspired it, but it does not have an *answer*, and it is unlikely to get one as it presently stands.   The question is of little use to anyone else in its current form, so it should be deleted.